# Is C# and Java duck-typed?

Tags: c#, java, inheritance, interface, duck-typing

Today we had a strange happening with a `close()` method.

Here is the code in doubt:

```
interface ICloseable
{
    void Close();
}

public class Closer
{
    public void Close()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("closed");
    }
}

public class ConcreteCloser : Closer, ICloseable 
{
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var concrete = new ConcreteCloser();
        concrete.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

So the question is:

The base class does not implement the interface.

**Why does the compiler accept the `Closer.close()` method as implementation 
of the interface method?**

Why is there not a least a warning in both Visual C# 2010 Professional
and Eclipse?

For me, C# and Java, are somewhat duck-typed in this case.

Can someone explain me the language considerations behind that please?
As both C# and Java do it the same way, there seem to be good reasons for that.

Comment: Close votes for off-topic? Why?

Comment: As a side note: .net also has "dynamic", which does allow for what is essentially duck-typing. However, this is completely unrelated to interfaces (this example).

Comment: @nawfal Do you mind suggesting a better one? This was just my try to communicate what is "wrong" for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For the question in the title

Interfaces are not Duck Typing.

[*Nominative* Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system):

> .. compatibility and equivalence of data types is *determined by explicit declarations and/or the name of the types*.

This includes Java/C# Classes and Interfaces. All types and relationships between types are defined *by name*.

[*Structural* Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system):

> .. compatibility and equivalence are *determined by the type's actual structure or definition*, and not by other characteristics such as its name or place of declaration.

This includes [Scala Structural Types](http://java.dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural) and C++ Templates.

[*Duck Typing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

> .. object's *methods and properties determine the valid semantics*.

This includes dynamically typed languages (e.g. Ruby, Python, JavaScript) and C#'s `dynamic`. I would also tentatively assert that Duck Typing is a subset/untyped form of Structural Typing; it is orthogonal to Nominative Typing.

## For the other questions

> Why does the compiler accept the Closer.close() method as implementation of the interface method?

Because the Close method is public and has a conforming signature. *Since ConcreteCloser inherits from Closer it also obtains all the base classes methods* - per [Inheritance Subtyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Inheritance_vs_subtyping) and [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (not all OOP languages use LSP) - *and thus conforms-to ICloseable*; it then chooses to implement the ICloseable interface *by name*. I am not sure what warning would be expected here.

*If C# was Structurally (or Duck) Typed, then Closer could be used in place of ICloseable, but it cannot;* `ICloseable c = new Closer()` is invalid as Closer is not defined to be *nominatively* related ICloseable.

> For me, C# and Java, are somewhat ducktyped in this case.

No; not unless talking about `dynamic` in C#. See above.

> Can someone explain me the language considerations behind that please? As both C# and Java do it the same way, there seem to be good reasons for that.

*This is by language design choice*; Interfaces are one method to support Nominative Typing in a *Single Inheritance* model. Scala (and Ruby) supports Traits; C++ supports Multiple Inheritance. Eiffel supports MI and also breaking LSP at the type level. Go figure - there is no "one right way".

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

The interface is a contract.  That contract states that the type has a method of the given signature.  It's not required that the member in question be defined, or re-defined, in the type itself.

This is not related to duck typing.  Duck typing means that the members aren't resolved at compile time; they're resolved at runtime.  Here the compiler is able to determine that the class implements the method *at compile time*.

Comment: I don't think Duck Typing *implies* that members aren't resolved at compile-time, although I've only really seen the term used in dynamically typed languages and I can't provide a "counter-case example of term usage" in Java/C#.

Comment: @user2246674 Yeah, there's probably a better way of stating that.  It's not actually a formal part of the definition, just a common implication of the term in certain contexts.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's where I'm hung up. In-practical-usage this makes sense, but .. could it be otherwise? Maybe just the accepted name changes (e.g. Structural Types in Scala) depending on other implications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand what is happening here, but I really want to know why it is handled that way. Think this can be errorprone too.

Comment: @user2246674 Yes, it can.  The best example that comes to mind is C++ templates.  Technically it's performing the validation at compile time, but it's not validating that the template type is, say, always of a given type, just that it has the given operations.

Comment: @MareInfinitus You can see the C# specs for a formal statement of how this all functions, if you're interested.  As for this being error prone; what error are you expecting to happen as a result of this functionality?

Comment: @Servy I could imagine that there are cases where you have two methods with the same name (for example close) and would expect that an interface shall be implemented to achieve a certain behaviour but get the behaviour of your base class without any warning. Perhaps some style checker could give a warning for that, if it is not intended.